# Marker animation in google-maps-react

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

Does anyone know how to add animation to Marker in google-maps-react library or any kind of google-maps library for React?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
<Marker defaultAnimation={google.maps.Animation.DROP} />
```

Answer (score -1):

It's in the docs.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations.

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  draggable: true,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  position: {lat: 59.327, lng: 18.067}
});

marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
```

Comment: I mean with the JSX syntax. I tried `<Marker animation={'DROP'}></Marker>` and all kinds but it does not work for me.